# How does the 'photo viewer' of win10 deal with the super large image(maybe larger than 500MB before decompressing)

Tags: c++, windows, image, jpeg

I tried to view a JPEG image which is 25054 * 45712 pixels using the 'photo viewer' of win10.

As I know, the image after decompressed will take up 3GB of RAM, but the truth is it didn't. When I scaled the image into full of its size, the 'photo viewer' took up only 300 MB of RAM!!! It's amazing!!!

I need to write a program with c++ to deal with the large image, maybe it can't be so perfect, but I want to learn from the amazing algorithm.

I want to find out how the 'photo viewer' did it, but got nothing.

So, if you know anything, please let me know, thank u so much!!!

Comment: Presumably you don't have to load all 45000 lines before starting to scale the top part of the image.

Comment: I can think of two strategies to keep memory consumption low: 1) only load/decompress the parts of the image that's actually being viewed by the user. 2) decompress the entire image to a file and then memory map it and only read the bits that you need to show on screen at any one time (and free what you've previously shown when the user pans around the image).

Comment: To Bo Persson: I think what you said is right, but how to do it is the biggest problem.

Comment: To Jesper：I have tried the first strategy you mentioned, and it brought me another question: if I want to get the data of line 20000 to 25000, I have to decompress the first 20000 lines of the image, even if I don't need them.(BTW, I am using the libjpeg to do the decompression, and I am not very familiar with it) As for your second strategy, I will try it, maybe it is the way.